# Tabs with dropshadow only around active

Tags: html, css, tabs, shadow, dropshadow

Is there a way to realize the following kind of shadow with CSS only?
[image]

So far I only managed to draw the shadow around the complete box without the recess around the inactive tab:

**[The Code Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xypjj7uy/1/)**

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="box">
    <div class="tabs">
        <span class="tab active">Bild</span>
        <span class="tab">Text</span>
    </div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 250px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2.5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
    margin: 16px;
}

.tabs {
    height: 30px;
}

.tab {
    display: inline-block;
    width: calc(50% - 2px);
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
}

.tab:not(.active) {
    /* Should be removed in the final solution with correct shadows... */
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
}
```

The solution doesn't need to take care of legacy browsers (< IE 10).

Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something like this - http://jsfiddle.net/zahedkamal87/xypjj7uy/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use This CSS

```css
.tab.active {
    box-shadow: 0 -5px 2.5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 99999;
}
.tab {
    background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
   
    text-align: center;
    width: calc(50% - 2px);
    
}

.content {
    box-shadow: 0 0 2.5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
    margin-top: 0;
    min-height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

Edit Your CSS

```css
.box {
- Remove this-
    /*box-shadow: 0 0 2.5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18); */ 
    height: 250px;
    margin: 16px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the "top-shadow" above the active tab as "narrow" as the others?